GoDot - is_inside_tree with HTTP Request
I am trying to get a response from my webserver, where i am hosting my config.json - to setup further stuff in my godot project. Instead of starting the HTTPRequest, i get the error message for line 13 (http_request.request("")) - Condition "!is_inside_tree() is true. Returning ERR_UNCONFIGURED". Don't know, if it helps, but this script is included by my main script, that only calls "getConfiguration", but inside the "_process()" - Function. The error itself only comes up once.
extends Node

var globalJsonConfig = "Initial"
var loading = false
        
func getConfiguration():
    var http_request = HTTPRequest.new()
    http_request.request_completed.connect(_response_parse)

    if loading == false:
        loading = true
        globalJsonConfig = "Loading.."
        http_request.request("https://MY_URL.COM/config.json")

    return globalJsonConfig

# Called when the HTTP request is completed.
func _response_parse(result, response_code, headers, body):
    var jsonLib = JSON.new()
    var json = jsonLib.parse(body.get_string_from_utf8())
    globalJsonConfig = json.body
    print("Loaded")


As the error states: A HttpRequest Node has to be inside the tree to use it's request function.
Assuming you have your current code as autoload:
Create a new scene and add an HTTPRequest Node to it. Then connect your current script to the root element and change HTTPRequest.new() to $HttpRequest
Remove the script from autoload and add the newly created scene to autoload. This will load it to the tree an you can call the function as you did before.
Another way if you do not want to have a HTTPRequest Node in your tree all the time:
extends Node

var globalJsonConfig = "Initial"
var loading = false
var httprequestNode = null
        
func getConfiguration():
    if httprequestNode == null:
        httprequestNode = HTTPRequest.new()
        httprequestNode.request_completed.connect(_response_parse)
        add_child(httprequestNode)
        if loading == false:
            loading = true
            globalJsonConfig = "Loading.."
            httprequestNode.request("https://google.com")

    return globalJsonConfig

# Called when the HTTP request is completed.
func _response_parse(result, response_code, headers, body):
    #var jsonLib = JSON.new()
    #var json = jsonLib.parse(body.get_string_from_utf8())
    #globalJsonConfig = json.body
    remove_child(httprequestNode)
    httprequestNode = null
    print("Loaded")

Here we add the HttpRequestNode to the tree before a request and then remove it after the request is completed. This code will only allow one request at once. You may need to extend it to react to errors, though
